# Mod rewrite htaccess worked on old server, not on new server

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-12.04

I have the following .htaccess file, which worked fine on my old host. I moved over to an AWS instance (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS), and it's no longer completely working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I know rewrite is installed, because this is partly working - it does send HTTP requests to HTTPS. Also, it does show up in the list of running modules. However, I can't use URLs without index.php anymore, as it all comes up as 404. Since this is an exact copy of a site that was already working, I figure I must have done something wrong when installing apache, but I can't imagine what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In spite of cool kids voting the question down without explanation, I managed to figure it out. The problem was that since it's HTTPS, changing AllowOverride to All in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default wasn't working. You need to edit default-ssl in that case.